# CSS Correctly positioning pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a input type range inside a div and I'm using the pseudo element 'before' as a circle. My intention is for it to be like the thumb at the starting position: I have the following html:

```
<div class="range">
    <input type="range" name="" class="progress" value="0" max="100" min="0"/>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.range::before{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   background-color: #69b6d5;
}
```

Here is a functioning [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sn3pqb69/)

My intention is to make the before element at the same position as the beginning of the range.

Comment: You're trying to make the red circle, and the yellow circle, at the same position?

Comment: At the same initial position, yes

Comment: @Aschab is this what you are looking for putting them side by side? https://jsfiddle.net/c9zn3609/ Adjusted width of `input` using `calc` and made `input` and `the `before` inline-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Added `inline-block` to `.range::before` and `input` and aligned them vetically using `vertical-align: middle`.
2. Set width of `input` to `width: calc(100% - 15px)`. This 15px is the width of the `.range::before` element.
3. Bring the `.range::before` over the yellow dot using `transform: translate(100%, 0)`

See demo below:

```css
/* RANGE */

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  background: #FFE000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 0px solid #FFE000;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFE000;
  border: 2px solid #FFE000;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #FFE000;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #FFE000;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  background: #FFE000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 0px solid #FFE000;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFE000;
  border: 2px solid #FFE000;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #FFE000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #FFE000;
  border: 0px solid #FFE000;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #FFE000;
  border: 0px solid #FFE000;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFE000;
  border: 2px solid #FFE000;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #FFE000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #FFE000;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #FFE000;
}
.range {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50vw;
}
.range::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #69b6d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <input type="range" name="" class="progress" value="0" max="100" min="0" />
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but how about adding this to `.range::before`:

```
.range::before {
    /* ... other css */
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sn3pqb69/2/)

Comment: not working on my end, so its not crossbrowser compatible or something

Comment: Huh. What browser are you using @Aschab

Comment: chrome, I just look the before circle a like 3 pixels below